# Beginner question: basic insertion idiom for JPA?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, openjpa

My "HelloJPA" code (below) tries to store an Employee in a datastore. However, any attempt to read the persisted object after committing the (resource local) transaction is rewarded with an "IllegalStateException":

```
Employee employee = ...
EntityManagerFactory factory =
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "HelloJPA", System.getProperties() );
EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction transaction = manager.getTransaction();
try {
    transaction.begin();
    manager.persist( employee );
    transaction.commit();
} finally {
    if (transaction.isActive()) {
        transaction.rollback();
    }
    manager.close();
}
System.out.println("Employee id == " + employee.getId() ); //<< IllegalStateException
```

OK, I guess, the manager took possession of my new-allocated employee object and it became unavailable once I committed the transaction.  But then, what's the common idiom to implement this simple operation, i.e., writing an object all the way to the datastore while still keeping read-only access to it?  The documentation (tutorials or API references) doesn't address this specifically, and the code samples I've found that use resource local transactions never seem to try to read the object after committing ... But surely there must be a trivially simple way to do it??

Thanks in advance for any help/pointers on this!

Comment: First off, did the created employee actually get persisted to the DB? Second, what does your employee Entity look like? Using an Entity after a resource local tran commits is a valid thing to do.

Comment: Hey, Rick, thx for your comment.

Yup, the employee gets added to the datastore. Of course this is a toy example, so the "employee" looks terminally simplistic:

@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = ...;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Basic
    private String name;

    @Basic
    private String position;

    // getters and setters omitted

}

Does that help?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the IllegalStateException? Rick's right this should work.

Comment: Could you also show your Employee class ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `employee` becomes detached after closing the entity manager but there is nothing that forbids accessing the `Id` annotated property of a detached entity. IOW, your code is correct and works with Hibernate and EclipseLink. Maybe search in OpenJPA's Jira for an existing issue or open a new one.